# Angular ng-init not called when scope variable is modified

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refresh

I have a **$scope.code.N3** variable that is filled by an asynchronous ajax call.

I have also a **$scope.data.selectedIRI** that is the value of an option in an html combobox.

I have an html snippet inside a table that shall refresh when the variable is updated:

This works and get refreshed when needed:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="t in code.N3" ng-if="t.subject==data.selectedIRI" ng-include="'displayPredicateObject'">
        <!-- Rendered by template -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

However this doesn't work (it works in some other part of my code, where this snippets is integrated into tags that are refreshed by angular):

```
<tbody ng-init="allTriples = code.N3">
    <tr ng-repeat="t in allTriples" ng-if="t.subject==data.selectedIRI" ng-include="'displayPredicateObject'">
        <!-- Rendered by template -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This also doesn't work:

```
<table ng-init="s = data.selectedIRI">
    <tbody ng-init="triples = getTriples(null, null, s)">
        <tr><td>[[triples]]</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here **getTriples(...,...,data.selectedIRI)** is never called, whereas **$scope.data.selectedIRI** is updated.

Is there any reason for that ?

Answer (score 0):

When you set initial value using ng-init, $scope.code.N3 was undefined since as you said it is set by a asynchronous call which has not yet occured , which causes ng-repeate to fail silently

```
<tbody ng-init="allTriples = code.N3">
    <tr ng-repeat="t in allTriples" ng-if="t.subject==data.selectedIRI" ng-include="'displayPredicateObject'">
        <!-- Rendered by template -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you Zohaib for the explanation. Any workaround to have this code working ?

Comment: I think you do not need to use ng-init, just use `ng-repeat="t in code.N3"`